# how to call multiple controller action from within any action in ZF?

Tags: zend-framework, helper

I have a controller action and I want it to be executed after any action. I have written an action helper with this method:

```
public function postDispatch(){    
    $actionstack = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('actionStack');
    $actionstack->direct('myaction', 'mycontroller');
}
```

But it seems that it stuck in a loop, what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Plugin, for example:

```
class Plugin_Sidebar extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

    public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        if($request->getModuleName() == 'admin')
        {
            return;
        }
        $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
        if (null === $viewRenderer->view) {
            $viewRenderer->initView();
        }
        $view = $viewRenderer->view;

        $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
        $view->videos = $yt->getUserUploads('MysteryGuitarMan');

    }
}
```

So put the actions you want in this plugin and these aciotns will be executed after all.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the `ActionStack` action helper, or simply put the logic of that method in your `postDispatch()`

Comment: + 1 Move the logic to your helper and your problem will be solved.

Comment: could u give me a sample code please. i dont want to use actionstack helper in my actions. because this way i have to write it in every controller action.

Comment: No you don't have to write it in every controller action, only in `preDispatch()`. You can also write a Controller plugin.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the postDispatch is called again after mycontroller->myaction has been dispatched, so it calls mycontroller->myaction again and again.